# What are the answers to the Boss's ciphers?

Tags: the-gold-factory

In [The Gold Factory](http://gamehelp16.github.io/thegoldfactory/), I'm having trouble deciphering the Boss's encrypted messages. How do I work them out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The numbers represent alphabets, where A is 1, B is 2 and so on.
2. Take the letter's position in the alphabet, add 8 and take that letter instead. (A becomes I, Y becomes G and so on)
3. Type in the code, but shift your hands one key to the left. (Instead of O, press I and so on. Only works on qwerty keyboard though.)
4. It's a base64-encoded string, use a base64-decoder for that.

First answer:

> master branch

Second answer:

> there is a treasure hidden somewhere, it is located at a secret place in the pacific ocean

Third answer:

> in a world full of blocks

Fourth answer:

> the plant is famous because of the ability to cure some diseases

Comment: I think they may have added new ones: `Code #5:
towiiag g se rir,oaoan ft ofo srtod tddyi ot mdy lugelelmwon foemsthiuaa ttclntclga bhhs`

Answer (score 4):

For the fifth and the hardest one:

**This is called "Rail Fence cipher".** It writes out the original texts in 3 rows in a "zig-zag" manner.
For example, the message `EXAMPLE` would be written as:

```
E . . . P . . 
. X . M . L . 
. . A . . . E
```

Then we will read it one row at a time, left to right:

```
EP
XML
AE
```

Thus, the cipher would be: `EPXMLAE`.

**Now, for question 5.** Do the rail fence cipher, THREE TIMES!

the gold factory was built long time ago, and it is the most famous gold factory in the world (original message)

```
t---g--- ---t--- --- ---l---o---t--- ---,---d--- ---t---m--- ---o---g--- ---t--- ---t---w---d
-h- -o-d-f-c-o-y-w-s-b-i-t-l-n- -i-e-a-o- -n- -t-i- -h- -o-t-f-m-u- -o-d-f-c-o-y-i- -h- -o-l-
--e---l---a---r---a---u--- ---g---m---g---a---i---s---e---s---a---s---l---a---r---n---e---r---
```

tg t  lot ,d tm og t twdh odfcoywsbitln ieao n ti h otfmu odfcoyi h olelarau gmgaisesaslarner

```
t--- ---t--- ---o--- ---h---f---w---t---i--- ---i---o---u---f---i---o---a--- ---a---s---a---r
-g-t- -o- -d-t- -g-t-t-d- -d-c-y-s-i-l- -e-o-n-t- - -t-m- -d-c-y- - -l-l-r-u-g-g-i-e-a-l-r-e-
-- ---l---,---m--- ---w---o---o---b---n---a--- ---h---f---o---o---h---e---a---m---s---s---n--
```

t t o hfwti ioufioa asargt o dt gttd dcysil eont  tm dcy  llruggiealre l,m woobna hfooheamssn

```
t---o---w---i---i---a---g--- ---g--- ---s---e--- --- --- ---r---i---r---,---o---a---o---a---n
- - - -f-t- -o-f-o- -s-r-t-o-d- -t-d-d-y-i- -o-t- -m-d-y- -l-u-g-e-l-e-l-m-w-o-n- -f-o-e-m-s-
--t---h---i---u---a---a--- ---t---t---c---l---n---t---c---l---g---a--- --- ---b---h---h---s--
```

towiiag g se   rir,oaoan   ft ofo srtod tddyi ot mdy lugelelmwon foemsthiuaa ttclntclga  bhhs (cipher in question)

Comment: Wow, thanks! How did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 3):

I've only worked out two so far. I'm not sure if the message is the same so I'll just post my method.

1. This is a simple number substitution cipher. Replace the letters with their appropriate number in the alphabet (1-A, 2-B, 3-C, etc.)
2. This one is a typical ROT cipher, ROT -8 to be exact. [Use this page to decrypt your message.](http://web.forret.com/tools/rot13.asp?rot=-8&cipher=&clear=&dir=encrypt) I already put in the setting.
3. The `;` characters give the hint here - you need to transpose each letter on the keyboard (one to the left), on a standard QWERTY keyboard.
4. The fourth message is Base64 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

For the fifth cypher:

> towiiag.g.se...rir,oaoan...ft.ofo.srtod.tddyi.ot.mdy.lugelelmwon.foemsthiuaa.ttclntclga..bhhs

Answer:

> the gold factory was built long time ago, and it is the most famous gold factory in the world

Comment: Thanks, though it would help to explain how to decipher that

Comment: @Zommuter See my answer for an explanation, it's quite long.